# How to discover "app" in a twig template?

Tags: twig

I have a Twig template that starts by setting a variable:

```
{%
set currentPath = path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'),
app.request.attributes.get('_route_params'))
%}
```

`app` isn't one of the parameters passed into the template, so what is it? How does it get set/found by Twig?

Comment: Which framework did you use?

Comment: @Rider_BY The framework is Symfony 2.8.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `symfony` (or `silex`), the variable `app` will be injected as a global automatically to the template

[reference](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/templating/app_variable.html)